# ObjectMapper configure method for mapper feature is deprecated

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I'm upgrading the version of jackson-databind to 2.14.2 version .But I noticed that ObjectMapper's configure method for mapper feature is deprecated.

Deprecated
Since 2.13 use JsonMapper.builder().configure(...)

Is it possible to edit configure of existing object mapper for mapper feature using that method? if possible, how to do that?

I have searching for the solution, but i just find the solution for configure new object mapper not for existing object mapper